# Why one of my Red Cherry Plum tree's stem turned yellow?

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees, growth, plums

Last week I seen that my Red Cherry Plum's stems are all green colored,
but near these days I noticed some differences and changes. Like one of its right thin stem has turned yellow, in the past its green. Another is that I can see the brownish color that's on top of the stem, maybe coming down a little by little, it might keep turning more brown downwards or below.
Why do you think it turned that way for the stems, and the color changes?
I think this is a color change day after day.

> The Plant Last Week
>   [image]
>
> The Plant Near These Days
>   [image]

Comment: The one the left is showing dieback form the top, otherwise, I refer you to your previous question on these plants  and its answer here http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/31089/what-kind-of-plant-will-my-red-cherry-plum-stems-grow-into

Answer (score 3):

I think it is nearly dead. Probably it didn't have enough strength to properly build roots.